# How to download the latest version of curl by shell script if I don't know version?

Tags: curl, awk, sed, grep, wget

I am trying to build a script that will automatically look for the latest version of curl from https://curl.haxx.se/download/ and install it on local host (Linux x86_64). If I try manually, I can lookup the latest version on website and use the appropriate wget command (with version name in URL). For example, if I want to download curl-8.0.1, the wget command would be

```
wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-8.0.1.tar.gz
```

To build this in a script, I will have to first extract the latest version available on Download site.

1. Is there a simple way to script it out in a way that it automatically checks for the latest version and builds the wget command in script?
2. If I download the index.html file from the site and grep for "download/curl-" and "tar.gz" with "head -1", I get a line as below. Is there a simple way using awk/sed/grep by which I can get the version number extracted from this line?

```
# grep -i "download/curl-" index.html | grep "tar.gz" | head -1

<tr class="even"><td>8.0.1</td> <td><a href="download/curl-8.0.1.tar.bz2">2.97MB</a></td><td><a href="download/curl-8.0.1.tar.gz">4.09MB</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td>
```

I tried with awk to get the version as below. This may not be the best and most efficient way. So I wanted to know if there is a better way to get latest downloadable curl version

```
# grep -i "download/curl-" index.html | grep "tar.gz" | head -1 | awk -F".tar.gz" '{ print $1 }' | awk -F"download/" '{ print $NF }'

curl-8.0.1
```

Comment: It might help to use this link to latest Linux x86_64 version: https://github.com/moparisthebest/static-curl/releases/latest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also get Curl from the Github repo using the api, if parsing the website's HTML feels too brittle:

```
curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/curl/curl/releases/latest | grep "browser_download_url.*gz" | cut -d : -f 2,3 | tr -d \" | head -1 | wget -qi -
```

The `head` is because one of the outputs would be a key. You could also use some other tool to get the info from the response, like `jq`, if you have that installed — they key point is, `/releases/latest` from the GH API will tell you what the most recent tag is.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a simple solution like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL="https://curl.se"
```

Using curl

```
$ curl -ks "$URL/download/" | tr ' ' '\n' | awk -F'"' -v url="$URL" '
 /download\/curl.*\.tar.gz/{
     n=split($2,a,"/"); 
     print | "curl -ks " url"/"$2 " --output " a[n]; 
     exit
 }'

$ ls
curl-8.0.1.tar.gz
```

Using wget

```
$ wget --no-check-certificate -q --output-document - "$URL/download/" | tr ' ' '\n' | \
awk -F'"' -v url="$URL" '
   /download\/curl.*\.tar.gz/{
       print | "wget --no-check-certificate -q " url"/"$2; 
       exit
}'

$ ls 
curl-8.0.1.tar.gz
```